# Better process or tools to deploy large number of Hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, impala, hcatalog

We are maintaining a data platform for a big financial institution. We have many Dev, SIT, and UAT servers and in each of them, we have 1000s of Hive tables. The challenge comes when we need to sync up all these servers to have identical hive table schemas. We do this schema sync up every 2 to 3 months.

Currently, we keep the table definition for each of the databases in a single file with DROP and CREATE statements and use the beeline command to execute the statements in the files. Each DROP and CREATE statement takes at least 5 seconds and for 1000s of tables, it takes hours to finish the deployment.

We are working on finding better tools or techniques to speed up the deployment. What we did so far is do some kind of comparative study to compare the performance of different tools like spark-shell, impala, and hcat commands. Our study showed that beeline performs better for CREATE/DROP statements than other tools/commands by at least 20-30%.

If we are not finding better tools, our next step is instead of deploying all the tables all the time, build a mechanism to keep a state or version of each of the tables in a table(preferably in RDBMS). Using this state table to identify what tables need sync up and deploy only those tables so that we are not deploying tables that didn't change since the last time we executed the schema sync up.

Posting this question in this forum to see if there are any better ways to deploy a large number of Hive tables.

Comment: Did you try to split file and execute in different sessions in parallel?

Comment: Yes, we tried that but that is not scaling well. We tried executing 3 to 4 database deployment in parallel but we can't go beyond that number without degrading the run time of individual DDL statements.

Comment: Are you creating external tables and data is already in hdfs? or just tables without data? Try to set hive.stats.autogather=false to prevent basic stats gathering when create table

Comment: Just external tables with data reside on HDFS. We will try with the setting to see if it improves the performance significantly.

Comment: Putting all ddl in one file and apply it during every migration is a very bad idea. May be you can deploy whatever changed and keep a track of changes using some change request method. Also, in cloudera you can synchup any schema from dev to prod or qa very quickly - its s3 to s3 migration and you can easily copy 1gb in seconds.

Comment: Or use some free version control tool like gitlab...

Comment: Thank you Koushik Roy for your comment. Can you please elaborate more on the Cloudera sync-up tool?. Was that for a data copy or schema copy?.

Comment: Its cloudera provided tool which copes data from prod to dev in seconds( like i said above). You probably need cloudera instance. Here is some help. If you want or have cloudera instance/license, i can check more. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/6/6.2/PDF/cloudera-administration.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiTlozPnLj1AhWy5nMBHS3hA1MQFnoECDUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1_tskAiJozCXtQ2oVKB0Nr

Comment: Can you also try coping just the db files using distcp. And then refresh the files/ tables?

Comment: Thank you again. I got it

Answer (score 1):

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE and MSCK REPAIR/RECOVER PARTITIONS can be extremely slow because basic stats are gathered.

Try to disable statistics auto gathering before creating tables:

```
set hive.stats.autogather=false;
```